# In ASP.net, what kind of IF statement could I use to hide a div if the image inside it matches the current page URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is within Sitefinity if that matters, and I am really new at ASP.NET and C#.

I have an image-based navigation element at the bottom of a page that links to different articles using the same template.   There are 5 articles, and I would like the link to the active page/article to be hidden so there is a grid of 4 image links.

Here's a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxDgr.png

Here is the code behind it:

```
@{
    string navTitle = string.Empty;
    string url = string.Empty;

    if (Model.CurrentSiteMapNode != null && Model.CurrentSiteMapNode.ParentNode != null)
    {
        if (Model.CurrentSiteMapNode.Title == "Home")
        {
            navTitle = Model.CurrentSiteMapNode.ParentNode.Title;
        }
        else
        {
            navTitle = Model.CurrentSiteMapNode.Title;
        }
        url = Model.CurrentSiteMapNode.ParentNode.Url;
    }
}
 <div class="foundation-stories-container">
    @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
    {
        @RenderRootLevelNode(node);
    }
</div>

@*Here is specified the rendering for the root level*@
@helper RenderRootLevelNode(NodeViewModel node)
{
string[] thisPage = (node.Url).Split('/');
string thisImage = thisPage[4] + ".jpg";
 <a href="@node.Url" target="@node.LinkTarget">
     <div class="foundation-story-block">
         <div class="hovereffect">
             <img src="[OUR WEBSITE URL]/stories/@thisImage" class="img-fluid">
             <div class="overlay">
                 <h2>@node.Title</h2>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </a>
}
```

So we're already getting the page URL and image file name

```
string[] thisPage = (node.Url).Split('/');
string thisImage = thisPage[4] + ".jpg";
```

Is this as easy as doing the following?

```
if (thisImage = thisPage) 
{
   foundation-story-block.AddClassToHtmlControl("hide")
}
```

Seems easy enough, but I don't know where to start.

I'm better at Javascript, so I do have a JS solution in place for this already, but I'd really like to find a cleaner way to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var active = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()

    var name = active;
    name = name.replace(/-/g, ' ');

    jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 
    0;
    };
});

$("h2:Contains('" + name + "')").closest(".foundation-story-block").addClass("hide");

});

</script>
```

This exists on the main template page.

1. Gets the last part of the URL
2. Sets that as a variable called "name"
3. Changes the dash to a space if there is one (most of the pages are associated with names so it's like /first-last)
4. Then it goes and looks at the  which is where the title of the page lives, and if it equals the "name" variable, the ".hide" class is added to the block.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? If so then you should post it to help out future users. If one of the below answers solved your problem then you should upvote and accept it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a click event to your elements with the `foundation-story-block` class. The reason I use `.on` instead of `.click` is because when using `UpdatePanel`s the click event won't fire after an UpdatePanel has it's update event triggered - you might encounter a similar problem with your dynamic binding so I used `.on` to avoid this.

```
$(".foundation-story-block").on("click", function() {
    // Remove the "hide" class from any elements that have it applied
    $.each($(".foundation-story-block.hide"), function(index, value) {
        // Remove the class using the "this" context from the anonymous function
        $(this).removeClass("hide");
    });

    // Add the "hide" class to the element that was clicked
    $(this).addClass("hide");
});
```

I haven't run this though an IDE so it might not be 100% correct but it will put you on the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes. Here is how:

```
...
@{
  var hiddenClass = thisImage == thisPage ? "hide" : string.Empty;
}
<div class="foundation-story-block @hiddenClass">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img src="[OUR WEBSITE URL]/stories/@thisImage" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="overlay">
              <h2>@node.Title</h2>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```